# How do Fabrials work?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

`In *Oathbringer*, Fabrial's are explained as working by means of trapping a spren. But there are multiple instances of Fabrials requiring *Stormlight* (Spanreeds, etc.) to work. So which is it?

Comment: I think both? they feed the Stormlight to the gem with the trapped spren?

Answer (score 1):

Fabrials need both a Spren and Stormlight. The spren helps determine what the fabrial does, and the Stormlight is the raw fuel.

We can see something similar with the Knights Radiant themselves:

> The Radiant has to swear oaths and *bond with a spren*. The oaths the swear and the spren they bond determine their *Order*, and what type of surgebinding they can do. However, even after swearing the oaths, they still need to take in Stormlight to be able to be able to actually surgebind.

Answer (score -3):

I believe this is because spren themselves are kept alive by stormlight so without it they would die. I do agree the specification for use varied but it could also have a direct relation to what the individual sprens main area of power was how much stormlight would be required.

Comment: Where is it mentioned that spren live on Stormlight?